# Are twin primes the only solution to this equation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Let $p,q_i, i \ge 1$ be primes, $m$ a positive integer. 
The equation
$$
p.\prod_{i=1}^m(q_i-1)-(p-1).\prod_{i=1}^mq_i=2
$$ 
for $m=1$ has all twin primes $p,q_1=p+2$ as solution.

Are there solutions for all $m\ge2$ ?

Comment: The simplest heuristic suggests probably yes, but it seems unlikely to be possible to prove this.

Comment: I'm not sure what to expect.  Without the primality condition,
we have for each $m$ an equation of the same degree as the number of variables 
(namely $m+1$),
so we expect some power of $\log N$ solutions up to $N$,
unless there's a polynomial family.  But primality costs
a factor of $(\log N)^{m+1}$, suggesting a delicate balance.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I think the leading term cancels, leaving us with a degree $m$ equation. This makes the probable situation more clear.

Comment: In the case $m=2$, you can take $q_1=p+2$ and $q_2=(p^2+p+2)/2$, so that your desired equation is just a polynomial identity. Standard conjectures then ensure that $p, q_1$ and $q_2$ are simultaneously prime, infinitely often

Answer (score 9):

An exhaustive search up to $1000$ finds the solutions
$$
(p,q_1,q_2) = (3, 5, 7), (11, 13, 67), (59, 67, 487),
$$ $$ 
(191, 277, 613), (251, 463, 547), (347, 571, 883)
$$
for $m=2$ and
$$
(p,q_1,q_2,q_3) =
(3, 5, 7, 37), (3, 7, 7, 11), (23, 37, 107, 131), (83, 137, 283, 797)
$$
for $m=3$.

Answer (score 4):

Given an odd prime $p$ and integer $m \geq 2$, we can set $q_1=p+2$ and then, for each $i$ with $2 \leq i \leq m$,
$$
q_i = \frac{ 4+ (p-1) \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} q_j}{2}.
$$
One can check that
$$
p \cdot \prod_{i=1}^m (q_i-1) - (p-1) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^m q_i =2,
$$
and each $q_i$ is a polynomial in $p$, of degree $2^{i-1}$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2^{i-1}]$).

It is plausible that this construction should produce infinitely many values of $p$ for which $p$ and each $q_i$ are simultaneously prime. That being said, I may be missing some local obstruction. While this very likely leads to infinitely many examples for $m \in \{ 2, 3, 4 \}$, the smallest with $m=4$ being
$$
(p,q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4)=(3,5,7,37,1297),
$$
examples with $m=5$ are rather thinner on the ground : the smallest is with $p=512351711$.